# Is there a way to set the maximum number of message redeliveries in ActiveMQ when using the Apache.NMS libraries?

Tags: .net, activemq-classic, nms

I'm using Apache.NMS 1.4. I need to be able to programmatically set the maximum number of times a message can be delivered before being placed in the DLQ (Dead Letter Queue). Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this to your connection string nms.RedeliveryPolicy.MaximumRedeliveries=5

Example:
tcp://localhost:61616?nms.RedeliveryPolicy.MaximumRedeliveries=5